# Do large number of relatives used to attend weddings in Puranic stories?

Tags: rituals, marriage

How weddings used to happen in Puranic stories ? Do large number of relatives used to attend the weddings ?

Was there Baarat where large number of people from the bridegroom side would  go to the bride's house for the wedding ?

Would there be a provision of  feast where the people attending the wedding eat food ?

Comment: Read the details on Bhagavana Shiva's marriage to Devi Parvati to clear your doubts.